# What remedies exist when `terraform validate` returns false positives?

Tags: terraform

I'm importing *a lot* of existing infrastructure to Terraform. On multiple occasions (and with various resource types), I've seen issues like the following...

After a successful import of a resource (and manually copying the associated state into my configuration), running `terraform validate` returns an error due to Terraform argument validation rules that are more restrictive than the provider's actual rules.

Example [imported](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/athena_database#import) configuration:

```
resource "aws_athena_database" "example" {
    name       = "mydatabase-dev"
    properties = {}
}
```

Example validation error:

```
$ terraform validate       
╷
│ Error: invalid value for name (must be lowercase letters, numbers, or underscore ('_'))
│ 
│   with aws_athena_database.example,
│   on main.tf line 121, in resource "aws_athena_database" "example":
│   11:     name       = "mydatabase-dev"
│
```

Error caused by [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/ec68e36cee6622a4d55346fa693dc0092d689358/internal/service/athena/database.go#L91) provider code:

```
"name": {
    Type:         schema.TypeString,
    Required:     true,
    ForceNew:     true,
    ValidateFunc: validation.StringMatch(regexp.MustCompile("^[_a-z0-9]+$"), "must be lowercase letters, numbers, or underscore ('_')"),
},
```

---

Since `terraform validate` is failing, `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` will also fail. Short of renaming the preexisting resources (which could be disruptive), is there an easy way around this?

Comment: Feature idea: Whitelist validation issues using a syntax similar to [`ignore_changes`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes).

Comment: If AWS and Hashicorp have incorrect validation code, then you should file an issue on the tracker for the provider and/or could submit a PR to correct the issue. It seems like a quick PR in theory, and the next provider update would contain the fix. I have done PR for `ValidateFunc` fixes like these before, and they are merged quickly in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can use the ignore_changes attribute in your Terraform configuration to tell Terraform to ignore any changes to the name attribute of the aws_athena_database resource. This will allow you to keep the existing name of the resource, even if it does not match the validation rules specified in the provider code. After adding the ignore changes attribute, you can run terraform validate again to verify that the error has been resolved. You can then run terraform plan and terraform apply as usual to apply the changes to your infrastructure.

Comment: It's not ideal, but this is an interesting idea. The name in the configuration can be modified to pass validation -- and, due to `ignore_changes`, that change won't be applied to the real deployment. It looks like this could solve my immediate problem. The downside is that it introduces risk of confusion or maintenance problems in the future.